# Error with mpich2 installing

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine

Am trying to install Mpich2 in Linux using virtual machine " Oracle VM " in windows.

when i write this command,

```
tar xfz mpich2-1.2.1p1.tar.gz
```

I got this error MSG:

```
tar : mpich2-1.2.1p1.tar.gz: cannot open: No Such file or directory
tar : child returned status 2
tar : Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Please help me in that, cause it is my first tim e doing this .

Thanks ^_^ .

Comment: The error is pretty much as described -- that file doesn't exist in the current directory. You need to run this command from the directory that `mpich-1.2.1p1.tar.gz` lives in.

Comment: cause i don't have good experience in that

tell me how

and how if i have this " tar " in windows 

how call it in linux

Answer (score -1):

Your command is not good.

Try this :

```
tar -xfz mpich2-1.2.1p1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Actually, `tar` doesn't require `-` for options.